# How to define Ruby Test::Unit testcase with `must`

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I had a test case of the following form:

```
require 'test/unit'
class SomeTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_should_do_action
   assert true
  end
end
```

and have re-written it using `must` as suggested in the book *A Test::Unit Trick to Know About*:

```
require 'test/unit'
class SomeTests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  must "do action" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

And when I run it, I get an `undefined method 'must'` error shown as follows:

```
SomeTests.rb:3:in `<class:SomeTests>': undefined method `must' for     SomeTests:Class (NoMethodError)  from
SomeTests.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'    from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'   from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'   from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'   from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'  from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'   from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'    from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>' rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [ruby -w -I"lib" -I"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0" "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*Tests.rb" ]
Tasks: TOP => default => test (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I thought that `must` might be a part of minitest, so I required 'minitest/unit' instead, but I still get an error. I also assume that `must` keyword isn't part of rspec, which I'm not using yet.

How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: Did you find any documentation on `must` in Minitest?

Comment: I looked in Test::Unit documentation and couldn't find any trace of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that method is not provided out of the box, but was developed by a third party. You need to add code described [here](https://github.com/practicingruby/rbp/blob/master/testing/test_unit_extensions.rb).

Comment: Great thanks for that. I'm just flabberghasted that the book would document a technique that requires a third party hack and not mention that bit; unless of course, it was previously in Test::Unit, and then depricated. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Something strange has occurred with this question, the first part where I introduce the question is missing. The book that I have been reading and where this problem arises from is 'Ruby Best Practices by Gregory T Brown'. The illustration in the book, doesn't show the require statements, so its not clear that there is an external dependency.